# Как найти из двух слов используя sql like например 'hello world' и 'world hello'?

Tags: mysql

Вот так:

```
FROM user WHERE LOWER (user_name) LIKE LOWER(?) or LOWER (address) LIKE 
LOWER(?) ", "%$name%","%$name%")
```

не получается.

Comment: `WHERE LOWER(user_name) LIKE (%substring1%)
  AND LOWER(user_name) LIKE (%substring2%)`

Comment: большое спасибо я проверил на datagrip работает. но на проекте выдает ошибку

Comment: "PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [SELECT drugstore_name, address FROM doru.drugstores WHERE LOWER (drugstore_name) LIKE(%substring1%) and LOWER(drugstore_name) LIKE(%substring2%) or LOWER (address) LIKE LOWER(?) ]; Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1)."

Comment: *на проекте выдает ошибку* Составьте корректный запрос, и ошибки не будет.